# Impossible to access Flask app through Vagrant private network and port forwarding (through domain name)

Tags: nginx, flask, vagrant, ubuntu-18.04, portforwarding

I just finished a Flask app that I want to host on my laptop (under Ubuntu 18.04) through a Virtual Machine (using Vagrant).

My network configuration is the following one :

[network configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvQdy.png)

I defined a domain name (through No-IP website), I configured my internet router for port forwarding (from 80 to 8080 and from 443 to 8443) and I added dynamic DNS to link my domain name to my internet router public IP address.

The command `host my_domain_name` gives me back my internet router public IP address.

Then I created a Vagrant private network (with 192.168.33.10 IP address) and a Vagrant port forwarding :

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/bionic64"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080, auto_correct: true
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 443, host: 8443, auto_correct: true
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.memory = "1024"
  end
end
```

Then I set a server using nginx + gunicorn + supervisor (following this tutorial instructions https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xvii-deployment-on-linux).

My nginx configuration is :

```
server {
    # listen on port 80 (http)
    listen 80;
    server_name www.my_domain_name;
    location / {
        # redirect any requests to the same URL but on https
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}
server {
    # listen on port 443 (https)
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.my_domain_name;

    # location of the self-signed SSL certificate
    ssl_certificate /home/vagrant/my_flask_app/certificates/certificate.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/vagrant/my_flask_app/certificates/key.pem;

    # write access and error logs to /var/log
    access_log /var/log/my_flask_app_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/my_flask_app_error.log;

    location / {
        # forward application requests to the gunicorn server
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location /static {
        # handle static files directly, without forwarding to the application
        alias /home/vagrant/my_flask_app/app/static;
        expires 30d;
    }
}
```

I configured the firewall on the VM so that following ports are opened :

```
~$ sudo ufw satus

Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

And for the host machine (my laptop) :

```
~$ sudo ufw status

Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
8080/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
8443/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
8080/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
8443/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

When, in a browser, I try to access the website through `192.168.33.10` it's working fine.

But when I try to use `http://www.my_domain_name` I get the **Welcome to nginx!** page.

I really don't get what I am doing wrong.

Since it's my first time dealing with website hosting I would gladly enjoy any help :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be misunderstanding the role of a private network. It's useful when you have multiple VMs that need to talk to each another, but it's not necessary in your case. It is necessary that whatever is listening from within the VM be listening on 0.0.0.0 and not 127.0.0.1. Fortunately, nginx already does the former.

On a laptop (running Ubuntu 14.04, because it's old), I provisioned a VM using

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.box = "ubuntu/bionic64"
    config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8000
```

ssh'd in, and installed nginx.

I could reach nginx from my laptop via `http://0.0.0.0:8000` and from elsewhere on my intranet via (in my case) `http://192.168.1.94:8000`. It wasn't necessary to use `ufw` from within the VM ("forwarded_port" takes care of that). Why `ufw` wasn't necessary from this laptop... may depend on something I forgot about doing a few years ago.

With the intranet part working, exposing nginx (and whatever happens to be proxied behind it) in your VM to the internet is a matter of router configuration.

Comment: Hello Dave and many thanks for the help ! Actually the problem was very simple. I was trying to access the website with `http://www.my_domain_name` but I realized that my domain name do not contain `www` (noob mistake... -_-) ! So just with `http://my_domain_name` it works fine. I realized it when reviewing my router configuration so I consider you solved my issue. Again thank you, I was on it since a week ^^